# Broadly, How to combine pre-rendered images in openEXR or openEXR Multilayer format, in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

My setup  i5 2500K processor @ 3.3 GHz  and 24GB ram.  Using Blender  v2.79b

I have created (unfortunately) a extremely memory hungry animation,  which my pc can't handle in one chunk!  I have broken it down into 15 layers,  and  can render  out about 2 layers at a time for the duration of the animation.  The intention being to combine these series of rendered images into a final combined series of images, that I can then  put it through the VSE to produce the MP4 video at the end.

Following extensive  browsing of slightly similar S/E  questions and to try and solve my problem, I've opted to test out using initially openEXR and  openEXR Multilayer format files types as the  file type for my 'stage 1'  2 layer rendered image outputs, these being supposedly (as stated in quite a few answers)  a good format for later compositing.
Anyway, I rendered out a sequence of (11) frames  in both formats, and  proceeded to use the image input node in the compositing window,  linked to a composite node.

Following  the mostly consistent advice on this node, picked up all the files, chose image sequence (it actually caught this automatically),  updated the no of frames to 11, start frame  to 1  and set the output file type to .png and hit the animated render button.
The result has been consistently bad. It  renders the first frame to a png successfully, and then runs through all the rest producing all blank/ black .png files,  whether the starting file type is openEXR or Multilayer !   - it even does it  if I give it .png  files to start with.

So question 1,  Why can't I get it to run through my file sequence and  pick up the images in  the files beyond the first file in the sequence - clearly I'm doing something wrong !

And question 2, assuming we can solve that problem, bearing in mind the intention to combine several strands of pre-rendered images,  is/are  the openEXR or openEXR Multilayer formats  the  right format to do this, or am I heading for another brick wall!  (and I'm not using any passes in these files)

A bit wordy but any/all help will be appreciated !

[image]

Comment: Well the simple mistakes - is ["Use Nodes"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/properties.html) enabled in the node editor header? is ["Compositing"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/post_process/panel.html) enabled in post processing? and sequencer disabled?

Comment: Hi Sambler, yes, all 3 are set as you suggest, ie enabled, enabled , disabled, but It still won't correctly process beyond the first file. If I use open EXR, I get black, if I use openEXR multilayer I get pink content in the .png  files produced, so I'm still stuck!

Comment: Well I've  simplified  things down to the minimum, still using my original render settings, it’s a 530 frame fly round. The blend file  'Stripped down test file.blend' was used to create 11 .png frames with a transparent background. I then fed them into 'REC-Composite-take1.blend'  as an image sequence in the node editor compositor window, and attempted to put a yellow background on all 11 .png frames.

Comment: Needless to say it failed and only produced one frame with  the yellow background from the  first frame in the sequence, thereafter all frames were just yellow.  So try it for yourself!
I think there must be a bug. I didn't bother trying any .exr files, as if it can't manage .png  there's not much point trying .exr!  I look forward to your results/comments!

Only problem is I can't get the giantcow  thing to work so not sure if you'll ever see my blend files!

Comment: I see you have 50 framestep in render tab. So you have first frame from 11 and others 10 are skipped.

Comment: No,  this takes frame 1, then frame 51, then frame 101, adding 50 each time, to get a selection of frames from the complete animation of 530 frames. I think It'll have nothing to do with why the image sequence node is not working properly.