# How to make the Image Input node process every file in a sequence of OpenEXR or OpenEXR Multilayer .exr files?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image, .exr

My setup  i5 2500K processor @ 3.3 GHz  and 24GB ram.  Using Blender  v2.79b

I have rendered out a set of 11 frames  in  OpenEXR and  OpenEXR Multilayer format. Each  set is produced from rendering a 3 layer blender file. 
Using an image node, set to image sequence  (as below)  these 11 files are connected to a composite node with the output set to produce .png files.

[image]

In both file types, the image node only processes the first file and produces blank files for the other 10, with the multilayer file format producing pink output .png files and the Open EXR files being black .png files.

I've read elsewhere that the pink colour is produced because there's no image there. I've  picked up the images  individually one by one in the image node, and it displays the image content of the file perfectly.

Why can't the image node process every file in the image sequence using the Animation button?

Can I have some help on this, I have an animation of 530 frames to composite and doing them one by one  rather wastes my processor!

Comment: Mixing standart EXR + multilayer EXR in one sequence is a deadend. If you need additional passes besides Z-depth then stick with multilayer for whole animation.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood what I've being doing, I'm not mixing them, I just tried each type as I couldn't get either one of them to work, and I'm not using any passes, just trying to get  from .exr to a .png

Comment: Can you share a stripped file? No need to attach textures, you can even replace your objects with simple cubes, just leave renderlayer setup untouched.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here,  need a bit of guidance,  is the 'stripped file'  one of my rendered .exr types, or are you speaking of my starting blender file?

Comment: Whole .blend file you are working with to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I'm trying to strip the file down, but having problems reducing the size and being able to replicate the render & layer settings I've got in my original  blend file - this may take some time!

Comment: Well I've  simplified  things down to the minimum, still using my original render settings, it’s a 530 frame fly round. The blend file  'Stripped down test file.blend' was used to create 11 .png frames with a transparent background. I then fed them into 'REC-Composite-take1.blend'  as an image sequence in the node editor compositor window, and attempted to put a yellow background on all 11 .png frames.

Comment: Needless to say it failed and only produced one frame with  the yellow background from the  first frame in the sequence, thereafter all frames were just yellow.  So try it for yourself!
I think there must be a bug. I didn't bother trying any .exr files, as if it can't manage .png  there's not much point trying .exr!  I look forward to your results/comments! 
only problem here I can't get the giantcow thing to work at all,  so not sure if you'll ever get to see the files above!!

Comment: If your file is too big, then upload to any filehosting you can

Comment: I may have cocked this up completely but  view this question and it may have the links to my uploaded files   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123314/broadly-how-to-combine-pre-rendered-images-in-openexr-or-openexr-multilayer-for